Load data from Delta table and write to Synapse dedicated SQL pool
I'm working on a project where we are trying to load multiple tables from Delta table into Synapse dedicated pool. The reason why we need the data in SQL is because the apps that read it are using .NET libraries and we do not intend to change any code there.
I'm aware that we are write data from Databricks straight into Synapse using the spark connector but I was exploring if I can read data from the delta table using a Synapse pipeline and write it to Synapse dedicated pool. I tried using the native delta lake connector and was able to read and write using a Synapse pipeline. I'm using the staged copy option available to a ADLS storage location.
My question is how can I use polybase to copy data efficiently from my delta lake to Synapse dedicated SQL pool? The documentation says that Polybase option is available and is the best option when writing data to Synapse pool

However, I do not see the Polybase option when configuring my copy activity. What I see is the below.

Am I missing something here? How do I enable Polybase so I can copy my data from source to sink?

Why don't you create an external table to the delta table, and then use that and a stored proc/pipeline to move it into the internal tables?

Thanks but that is just another option to do it. My question is around how come Polybase option is not available even though the documentation says that it is.


I do not see the Polybase option when configuring my copy activity. Am I missing something here? How do I enable Polybase so I can copy my data from source to sink?

Ploybase option is available for the Azure Synapse Analytics (formerly Azure SQL Data Warehouse and serverless SQL pool) as sink.
To enable Ploybase option select dataset as Azure Synapse Analytics

Add your dedicated SQL pool details as below and connect it.

and the Polybase option is enabled you can see in below image.


This option is not appearing for me. Did you select Delta table as the source?

can you add image of your source settings to get better understanding
